# Duplicate dominating parents when using Deterministic Crowding in Genetic Algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithm

This is pseudocode for using deterministic crowding:

```
for i from 0 to N/2
     p1, p2 = select_two_random_individual()
     c1, c2 = crossover(p1, p2)

     c1 = mutate(c1)
     c2 = mutate(c2)

     if((d(p1, c1) + d(p2, c2)) < (d(p1, c2) + d(p2, c1))
          population.add(Winner between p1 and c1)
          population.add(Winner between p2 and c2)
     Else
          population.add(Winner between p1 and c2)
          population.add(Winner between p2 and c1)
```

Which `d` is a function that determines the difference between two individual.

The question is, what happens if an individual gets selected two times as parent, and wins over its child both times? Do I end up with duplicate individual in new population?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is not uncommon to have duplicate individuals in a population. It is in fact expected that at some point all solutions will converge to an optimal, this is where all solutions in a population are the same. This is only a problem when there is premature convergence.

Comment: I'm using Deterministic Crowding to solve premature convergence problem. How should I deal with the duplicates that DC produces?